# Get Chinese characters unexpectedly when using _snwprintf

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio

When using _snwprintf, I am getting Chinese characters instead of English.

```
wchar_t outfile[1024];
char const*outf = "test";
_snwprintf(outfile, 1024, L"%s.zip", outf);
_wfopen(outfile, L"wb");
```

The file name should just be "test" but in the output file it is in Chinese.

When I try like this there no problem, the output file contains English as expected:

```
_snwprintf(outfile, 1024, L"justtest.zip");
_wfopen(outfile, L"wb");
```

How can I correct the first code block, in order to get the file name shown correctly in the output file?

Comment: "I am getting chinese characters when using _snwprintf " and "file name is written in chinese characters" - What is the problem?? See [ask], provide a [mcve].

Comment: The problem it self in the title ! i get every time chinese characters when using the first code, but the right characters when using the second code ! i am looking for a solution to solve the first code in order to use random filename.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Which platform are you working on (o/s and compiler)?  Most likely, it seems you are working on Windows with MS Visual Studio — the names prefixed with an underscore match the way MS does business, rather than the way standard C does business.  It matters because you have to look at Microsoft's manual pages, rather than trying to look at the C standard. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ The C standard doesn't define a function `_snwprint()`, but does define `swprintf()` in `<wchar.h>` with the prototype `int swprintf(wchar_t * restrict s,
size_t n, const wchar_t * restrict format, ...);` which includes the length implied by the `snwprintf()` name in Microsoft's realm, without including the `n` in the function name.  There's also no standard C `_wfopen()` or `wfopen()` function at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wchar_t outfile[1024];
char const*outf = "test";
_snwprintf(outfile, 1024, L"%s.zip", outf);
_wfopen(outfile, L"wb");
```

`outf` is ANSI (`char`), but `outfile` is UTF-16 (`wchar_t`), and `_snwprintf` expects `wchar_t`. Visual Studio 2015 issues the following warning:

> ```
> warning C4477: '_snwprintf' : format string '%s' requires an argument
> of type 'wchar_t *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'const char *'
> ```

You need to change the code to use `wchar_t`:

```
wchar_t outfile[1024];
const wchar_t* outf = L"test";
_snwprintf(outfile, 1024, L"%s.zip", outf);
wprintf(L"%s\n", outfile);
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you can't conveniently change the argument to a wide string, you can use `%hs` to specify that the argument is a narrow string.

Comment: @HarryJohnston i used your solution and solved the problem thank's.